# How can I have an exception show in debugging output that doesn't cause a "catch"

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

This may be a basic question but I have not been able to find an answer from searching. I have code that is causing an exception to be written to the Output -> Debug window in Visual Studio. My `try...catch` is proceeding to the next line of code anyway. The exception is with a NuGet package.

Does this mean an exception is happening in the NuGet package and is handled by the Nuget package? How can I troubleshoot this further?

```
private void HandleStorageWriteAvailable(IXDocument doc)
{
    using IStorage storage = doc.OpenStorage(StorageName, AccessType_e.Write);
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Attempting to write to storage.");

        try
        {
            using (Stream str = storage.TryOpenStream(EntityStreamName, true))
            {

                if (str is not null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string test = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", 100000));
                        var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
                        xmlSer.Serialize(str, test);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Something bad happened when trying to write to the SW file.");
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to open stream {EntityStreamName} to write to.");
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception happens on the line `using (Stream str = storage.TryOpenStream(EntityStreamName, true))` when the exception happens the code proceeds to the next line *not* the catch.

Is this normal behaviour if that exception is being handled by something else? I've never seen this before.

Comment: > Does this mean an exception is happening in the NuGet package and is handled by the Nuget package?
Probably this. If the original code does not rethrow the exception, you will not catch it. To investigate it more, you could check source codes of NuGet if it available (they usually are)

Answer (score 1):

In general, a method called TrySomething will be designed so that it won't throw an exception, but return some sort of error code instead.

Check for example the `Dictionary` class : it has an `Add` method which can throw an `ArgumentException` if the key already exists, and a [`TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-5.0%5D) method which instead just returns false.

Chances are, your IStorage implementation of TryOpenStream also has an OpenStream method, and the Try version is just a try/catch wrapper which outputs the error to the Console in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it happens on that line?
However there is a setting that enables breaking handled exception in "Exception Settings" dialog (Ctrl+Alt+E). For each type of exception you can control. Here is a link that explain how it works : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: I know it happens on that line by setting a breakpoint before the line with the issue and executing one line at a time. I'll look at that link, thanks.